# google maps API v3 : computing distance between 2 points on a polyline

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am a bit confused with my code and I don't really know which way to go.

Let's consider I have a car marker that is running through a polyline.

I change its position each 500 ms by setting a timer :

```
function animate() {
  var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(distanceFromBeginning);
  carMarker.setPosition(p);

  distanceFromBeginning += step;

  timerHandle = setTimeout("animate("+(distanceFromBeginning)+")", tick);
}
```

I also added the fact that my car can be dragged on the route :

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(carMarker, 'dragend', function(e) {

    var p = find_closest_point_on_path(e.latLng,polyline.getPath());
    console.log("position is : " + p);
    carMarker.setPosition(p);
    console.log("dragend")
});
```

Now that I have a new position after dragging the car on the polyline, how can I get its distance from the start location so I can update it correctly in my timer?

Comment: It can be done, but requires 1. finding the previous vertex in the polyline 2. the distance from the start of the polyline to that vertex, 3. the distance along the polyline past that vertex (might be negligible).  Somewhere I have the pieces to do that, but not all in one place.

Comment: Would there be a more simple approach that what I did? Or do I have to do the steps you described each time I drag the marker?

Comment: If you have a "`google.maps.LatLng` or `string` address" at begin (or end) point and then if you drag the marker to a "`google.maps.LatLng` or `string` address" position, you can easily accomplished with [Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/intro). If thats your case tell me so i can provide you a simple example.

Comment: I have the coordinates of the starting location and end location, so I'd be glad if you can provide a simple example so I can understand it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the coordinates for the end location (lets call the "destination"), and assuming that on your 'dragend' event you set the coordinates for the car (let call "origin") location you can call this function on your listener:

```
function calculateDistances() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        console.log(results[j].distance.text);
        console.log(results[j].duration.text);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Check this example on jsfiddle based on the Google documentation(look the result on your console)](http://jsfiddle.net/d2swg8yz/1/)

Fell free to reply if you need more help with this code or if it's not what you want.

Comment: yay, that works perfectly, thank you ! I just have a little problem : I have to pause my simulation, drag the car and restart the simulation so the new position is taken into account, but if I don't pause, I can't drag the car to a new location, due to the fact that the calculeDistances() is asynchronous I believe, and that the distance is changed

Comment: But I can fix it by putting a condition that when I am dragging the item, the timer is stopped. Thanks a lot !